# transfer data from low version (2.1) to higher version (4.0) in couchbase

Tags: couchbase

I am running a couchbase cluster (v2.1). Now I have a couchbase cluster (v4.0) provisioned. I want to transfer data from the 2.1 cluster to the 4.0 cluster. Can I just simply use the XDCR through the web console to do that? That is I replicate the data from the v2.1 cluster to the v4.0 cluster.

Any risk that I might lose the data in the v2.1 cluster?

Thanks for the hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can simply use XDCR to replicate the data to the new cluster. It is robust and is designed to replicate data safely. Note that XDCR uses some resources, so make sure your source cluster has enough CPU and memory headroom. Couchbase best practices recommend approximately 1 core per replication steam and at most 80% of RAM allocates to Couchbase.